# DB2/HIbernate: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, spring-data-jpa, db2

While trying to insert data into table which has only 12 columns it gives the error regarding 13th Paramater. DUmped SQL doesnt show that there is any 13th parameter

I am using Spring data jpa to insert data into database.

```
X x = new X();
```

then using setters 12 parameters are set.

Exception results:

```
insert into insert into X (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?): com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10145][10844][4.19.26] Invalid parameter 13: Parameter index is out of range. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.l(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gp.setString(Unknown Source)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:343)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrateId(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2835)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2804)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3076)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3521)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:303)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)


enter code here
```

Comment: Please show us the code relevant to triggering the insert statement.

Comment: You can trace the DB2 JDBC driver. Look at [Examples of using configuration properties to start a JDBC trace](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvcfgtr.html). You can place these properties to `DB2JccConfiguration.properties` file in your CLASSPATH instead of using `db2.jcc.propertiesFile` property. Trace file should show you where the error is exactly.

Comment: Thanks Mark, let me try same